# È scorretto scrivere "Scrivete un email" senza apostrofo?

Tags: orthography, articles, gender

È scorretto scrivere "Scrivete un email" senza apostrofo?
A me email suona come un nome femminile e quindi io l'apostrofo lo metterei. Tuttavia il dizionario riporta: e-mail s. ingl. inv.; in it. s.f. inv. **(anche m.)**

Comment: Per curiosità: quale dizionario hai consultato?

Comment: ["Un mail"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22un%20mail#q=%22mandami+un+mail%22), al maschile, viene usato. Perché non "un email"?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, i dati di Google su una singola stringa non dicono molto. Qualcosa di più, semmai, (ma guarda [qui](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1225/is-google-ngram-viewer-really-useful)) può darlo un confronto fra due stringhe, e non con la ricerca generica ma con Google Ngrams, che è fatto apposta, e [“un mail” pare in forte minoranza rispetto a “una mail”](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un+mail%2Cuna+mail&year_start=1990&year_end=2015&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cun%20mail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuna%20mail%3B%2Cc0), per quel che vale.

Comment: E aggiungo che nel Ngram del mio commento che precedente numerose occorrenze di “un mail” derivano da locuzioni come “un mail server”, “un mail hub” e simili.

Comment: @DaG Non ho detto che è prevalente, ma che esiste e che viene usato *in the wild*. Forse è semplicemente per metonimia da "un messaggio e-mail", ma da quella ricerca mi sembra innegabile che mail al maschile non è solo un errore.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider Il dizionario che riporta e-mail (anche m.) è il [Sabatini-Coletti](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/E/e-mail.shtml).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, è vero che qualcuno prima o poi avrà usato “mandami un mail”, ma che ce ne siano occorrenze in rete di per sé non dice nulla. Ci sono molte occorrenze di *“qual'è”, di *“c'è la faccio”, di *“non centra niente”... Quindi non è chiaro come si possa concludere che «da quella ricerca mi sembra innegabile che mail al maschile non è solo un errore». Attenzione: non sto dicendo che “un mail” sia censurabile; sto solo dicendo che una ricerca con Google non permette di dire che sia “giusto”, perché altrimenti *“c'è la faccio” sarebbe ancora più giusto (ha il doppio delle occorrenze).

Comment: @DaG I tuoi esempi mi sembrano poco calzanti perché riguardano tutti l'ortografia, non l'uso della lingua parlata. Questa non è una questione di sbagliare perché non si sa una regola. Possiamo solo limitarci a vedere come viene usato quel termine. Google mostra che nel 6.75% delle occorrenze "mandami un mail" viene usato al maschile anziché al femminile. Secondo me non sono trascurabili: non è tutta gente a cui la 'a' è rimasta per sbaglio nella penna (tastiera), c'è qualcuno che usa veramente quel termine al maschile coscientemente. Questo intendevo dire con "non è solo un errore".

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Condivido appieno le tue conclusioni, ma non il modo per arrivarci. L'unico dato oggettivo che abbiamo è “il tal fenomeno linguistico è presente nel x% dei casi”: dedurre da questo se è “sbagliato”, substandard, minoritario, dialettale, umoristico o che altro richiede o altri dati o un'interpretazione soggettiva non priva di arbitrarietà (interpretazione che in questo caso, ripeto, condivido).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: (Per un esempio non ortografico, bensì di genere grammaticale, confronta la diffusione relativamente alta, ma “errata”, di “le aspirapolvere” rispetto a “gli aspirapolvere”.)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni:  Molti degli esempi di "un mail" di Google non sono in italiano, ma in altre lingue.

Comment: @Charo Sono arrivato fino a pag. 10 dei risultati di Google e ne ho trovato uno solo che non fosse in italiano. Detto questo, Google personalizza i risultati, forse tu trovi più risultati in lingue spagnole rispetto a noi.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Certo! Io trovo molti esempi in spagnolo, in francese, in catalano...

Comment: Ricordo, senza tornare nel merito, che Google stessa sconsiglia di usare le proprie ricerche (a parte Ngrams) a fini di studi linguistici, quasi fossero concordanze su corpora testuali. Infatti, i risultati sono diversi a seconda di chi effettua la ricerca (lingua, nazione, ricerche precedenti se si è “loggati” etc.) e soprattutto non sono puramente testuali, ma vagamente semantici: in ricerche normali, oltre ai termini cercati, si ottengono anche pagine con sinonimi e termini collegati, e persino cercando una stringa tra virgolette gli algoritmi tengono conto di altri fattori.

Comment: Riguardo a "un mail" o "una mail" sono in ogni caso **errori.** La posta elettronica si chiama *email* (o *e-mail* a seconda del dizionario e della nazione).

Answer (score 11):

***e-mail***: (secondo Treccani  è   un sostantivo femminile), quindi ***"un e-mail" non è corretto.***

> - ***e-mail ‹i mèil› locuz. ingl. [comp. di e-2 e mail «posta»], usata in ital. come s. f.*** – Nel linguaggio delle telecomunicazioni e dell’informatica, lo stesso che posta elettronica (v. posta1, n. 3 f); estens., il messaggio trasmesso con tale mezzo: scrivere, inviare, ricevere una e-mail (o per ellissi, una mail); mi dai la tua e-mail?; comunicare, mandare un documento per e-mail; anche in funzione attributiva (posposto al sost.): avere più di un indirizzo e-mail.

***"un'e-mail" o "una e-mail"?***

> - L’elisione è un fenomeno che comporta la perdita della vocale terminale non accentata di una parola davanti alla vocale iniziale della parola successiva. Nell’italiano scritto contemporaneo il fenomeno, perfettamente regolare, sembra in netta regressione. ***Entrambe le forme, un’e-mail e una e-mail sono comunque corrette.***
> - Al plurale, l’elisione è meno usata se non rara; è di sapore antiquatamente letterario se la vocale iniziale della parola seguente è diversa dalla marca del plurale con cui termina l’articolo o l’aggettivo (l’edere è ricercato e raro; quell’anime è decisamente affettato, a meno che non si stia mettendo su pagina una parodia dell’italiano letterario antico).

[Treccani.it](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_140.html)

Comment: La risposta è perfetta se intendiamo "email" come "messaggio di posta", ma se lo interpretassimo come "indirizzo di posta" (ad esempio, "inserisci un [sottinteso: indirizzo] email") potrebbe risultare corretto usare "un"

Comment: @Stubborn -          Non penso, Treccani  fa l'esempio : ***mi dai la tua e-mail?*** comunque al femminile.

Comment: È vero, hai ragione

Answer (score 4):

Il genere dei forestierismi in italiano è ampiamente discusso (e risolto) dall'Accademia della Crusca.

> Attribuire il genere che ha la parola corrispondente in italiano o che ha originariamente nella lingua d'origine (per le lingue come l'italiano che attribuiscono il genere ai sostantivi).

In caso di parole molto recenti o non radicate la questione si fa più complessa, non essendo stabilito un uso comune:

> Per molte parole inglesi (l'inglese come è noto classifica come neutri i sostantivi) che entrano nell'italiano è difficile rintracciare un corrispondente italiano da cui trarre il genere; inoltre per i forestierismi molto recenti e ancora non radicati nella nostra lingua non possiamo avvalerci neanche dell'aiuto dei dizionari che ancora non li registrano.  **Nessuna delle due forme è sbagliata**.

Nel caso in questione quindi, oltre all'uso comune al femminile, e-mail è tradotto come *posta elettronica* e dunque va considerato femminile in italiano.

[Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/genere-forestierismi)

Answer (score 1):

Vittorio Coletti nel suo libro 
*Grammatica dell'italiano adulto* (Il Mulino, Bologna, 2015) spiega:

> Il problema dell'assegnazione del genere si pone anche quando importiamo parole straniere, specie dall'inglese, che non fa distinzioni di genere nei nomi. Sembra che una parte la faccia il traducente, cioè la parola italiana che traduce quella del prestito. Per cui in italiano *hobby* è maschile («un hobby costoso») perché *svago*, maschile, lo traduce meglio di *passione*, femminile. Così diciamo *la Panda* perché l'iperonimo è *automobile*, ma *il panda* perché il nome cui è più associabile è *orso*, *orsetto*, maschile, e *chador*  forse è maschile per via di *velo*. *E-mail* si sta stabilizzando al femminile per la pressione del traducente *posta*, anche se resiste ancora il maschile (su messaggio).

Quindi, secondo questo autore, non sembra che la forma maschile "un e-mail" possa considerarsi "scorretta", anche se la forma al femminile è quella che si usa di più.